# getting strings and string length from a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

my task was to define a function that takes a list of names and returns a dictionary of names + the corresponding length of each string (Name).
The code worked just fine:

```
    def toDict(namelist):
            lengths = []
            for i in namelist:
                    lengths.append(len(i))
            namedict = dict(zip(namelist, lengths))
            return namedict
            print(namedict)
```

However, 2nd part of the task was to do it in one line only and I'm getting stuck a bit there... please help.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to use a `dict` comprehension:

```
namedict = {name: len(name) for name in namelist}
```

If you need your entire function definition to be on one line, I’d suggest using a lambda:

```
to_dict = lambda name_list: {n: len(n) for n in name_list}
```

As mentioned in the comments, even though I personally prefer the lambda approach - and though I feel it’s a solid use case for it - it’s still possible to use a `def` and have a normal function on a single line; you’ll just need to put the body immediately after the colon `:` as shown below.

```
def to_dict(name_list): return {n: len(n) for n in name_list}
```

Comment: You don't need a `lambda` to make it one line, you can put `def` and the body on the same line, immediately after the `:` for the `def`, in lieu of going to another line and indenting (it's not the worst thing ever as long as you don't use `;` to put multiple lines on one line): `def to_dict(name_list): return {n: len(n) for n in name_list}`

Comment: Yep, that’s definitely a good point. I also figured you can use `def` and have the func definition on one line, however I personally find it a bit more unwieldy than a lambda. Still, I’ll see if I can mention that in the answer.

Comment: PEP8 style guide says "Always use a `def` statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a `lambda` expression directly to an identifier. [`def`] means that the name of the resulting function object is [the actual name] instead of the generic `<lambda>`. This is more useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression)". Character count is a mere three characters longer to get that useful name.

Comment: The short form of that rule is: "Never name a `lambda`"

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
>>> li = ['one', 'three', 'four']
>>> dict(zip(li, map(len, li)))
{'one': 3, 'three': 5, 'four': 4}
```

How it works:

1. `map` applies the function `len` to each element in `li`
2. `zip` forms a tuple of name and length
3. `dict` takes the tuple and forms a dictionary.